# Remote Desktop connection without domain name

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a Windows Server 2016 cloud hosted machine using remote desktop, yet whether I enter the user name as `Administrator` or `.\Administrator`, I always get a "login failed" message for `MYMACHINENAME\Administrator`.

How do I force rdp to connect without any domain name?

Comment: There's no such thing as a Windows account that doesn't have a domain name, just accounts that aren't part of an *Active Directory* domain. Specifically, local accounts are members of the local computer's domain.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I never said there was a Windows account without a domain name. I asked how to log in without specifying a domain name.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes, that worked for me, thanks, but I see that has already been added as an answer too.

Comment: Ah.... I didn't even read that answer but I see that now too. No worries, glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the computername of the remote system, e.g., `CLOUDHOSTEDVM\Administrator`. When you use `.\` (or no prefix) via RDP, it assumes the domain/computer name of your connection, not the target computer.

Answer (score 4):

imaging you want to remote desktop from A to B as user 'someone' on the B machine.
you could do:

```
user: \someone
```

or

```
user: B_MACHINE_NAME\someone
```

if you want to login as user 'someone' from machine A.

```
user: .\someone
```

Comment: This solution was suggested back in 2018.  Both versions of the syntax was fully explicitly explained by the accepted answer

Comment: @Ramhound:  I disagree.  The accepted answer doesn't mention using a backslash alone, without a leading period, as the equivalent of the computer name of the remote system.  That's a handy trick.

Comment: @SimonTewsi - Yes; It actually does.

Comment: @Ramhound No, it doesn't. The leading backslash with no domain mentioned is also new to me and helpful!

Comment: @ygoe - It absolutely does. **“When you use .\ (or no prefix) via RDP, it assumes the domain/computer name of your connection, not the target computer.”** Why exactly are you replying to a comment I submitted 3 years ago?

Comment: "No prefix" is "" like in "user", not "\" like in "\user". That's a difference, I tried both! I replied because I read it today.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this again, I was having the same problem logging into a machine with the same user name I use on the local machine, but a different domain.  My computer would always drop the machinename\ or .\ from the username even when it was saved in the RDP file since the user name matched what I was currently logged in with.  The solution I found was to combine the two like machinename\.\username (I edited the RDP file with notepad - I'm not sure if the user interface would take it).  With that, remote desktop now shows .\username when I load up the RDP file and forces the username from the remote system.

Comment: This solved my problem! Even though I have different user names locally and remotely, the saved connection would always ignore my domain prefix unless I retyped it interactively. Now I can finally use the saved user name. And it can simply be typed in the RDP config dialog, I've tried it and verified the saved file with a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

This ancient problem remains in Windows 10 till the day of writing (September 2022). The built in RDP client was working all right till a few weeks back, but probably after an update, it started prefixing users with the target computer name; so login fails with "authentication error (Code: 0x800706be)".

The solution that worked for me: I downloaded the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from Microsoft Store:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRFJ3PS
```

This client works without any issues.

Comment: This might explain my mystery, I observed the remembered username that was added to my RDP client from an old cache is just the username, no machine name at the start of it.
But now if I login to a new machine it automatically appends the target machine name to the beginning of the username, your answer, seems to explain why, you deserve more approvals.
The reason I didnt want the appended machine name is of course it would invalidate the login if I changed the machine name after saving the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

With windows 10 use \\Administrator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can also use localhost\administrator to connect.