# Remote Desktop with W10: domain name appended to username

Tags: remote-desktop

How do I prevent W10 from automatically appending its domain name (which is our corporate AD one) to any username I use to connect to all sorts of remote computers by RDP? Exact same issue is also happening with SMBv2. In both cases the domain name seems to be added by the Windows Security window as that's the last stage where the username still shows up w/o domain name - and upon entering the password and trying to connect it returns "Your credentials did not work" and "The login attempt failed" displaying the username with domain name appended this time. Basically I want it to completely forget the fact it's part of a domain for such connections. I'm well aware that prefixing all those usernames with \ helps (e.g. as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1334115/remote-desktop-connection-without-domain-name)) but what I'm after is making desired behaviour ***default***, so that I don't have to use \ at all, like with W7 for years and years in the past. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> like with W7 for years and years in the past.

Times, systems and security changed (and we have all been caught with these changes).

Windows 10 and 11 now you must use the domain name in the systems you are using.

It may be that the number of members of your workgroups is pushing the limits of workgroups (normally 10 max).

Also it may relate to the way your IT department sets up machines.

So just use it and adapt as we all had to do.

Comment: John: thanks for your reply. I do agree that adapting is generally the way to go. Meanwhile it may surprise you but I somehow got it working "my way" on my previous corporate laptop running exact same W10 build as the one on my new laptop that I recently got instead of that one. Unfortunately I left no notes back then.

Comment: Something may have been cached. In any event, you do need domain names now.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to use a w/a then, e.g. save all my RDP connections as .rdp files with the last line "username:s:\\<username>" in them all (a single back slash is no good - a double one is required, so that one of them sticks).

Comment: And that will be using your domain name as I posted above.

Comment: Assuming you mean I do have to use domain name from now on I can't do that: all of those remote machines are not on our AD and so have no domain whatsoever: I think they're all part of some default workgroup. But either way the w/a with "username:s:\\<username>" in .rdp files works fine here.

Comment: There may have been some setup with the Workgroup causing this.  Vanilla Workgroups (using them here) do not need domain names (not here). So something, somehow was set to require them. And If you are using Microsoft Accounts, be sure to use the entire Microsoft Account email address.

Comment: So it's the Workgroup functionality on *my* laptop that is being used for the outgoing RDP connections (despite it's on AD) and is believed to be causing it because of some changes in its settings? Just wondering what logic MS were pursuing when making those changes: that all remote machines use the same domain name as mine from now on for the "old style" behaviour where entering the password for the saved username was the only thing to do? But that's not even always possible as some of them belong to other companies or individuals... Sorry if I'm not getting the point though.

Comment: I am not sure why in your case.  Vanilla workgroups work without domain names.

Comment: Also make sure the number of members of your workgroup is not pushing the limits. That may cause your issue.

Comment: Just checked and my laptop in question turns out to be in a workgroup and not in a domain as I was thinking before (IIRC I saw some of my previous ones in a domain). Can that coexist with the fact that it's on AD? I'm badly lacking Windows knowledge here.

Comment: One machine cannot be both in a Workgroup and on a Domain. Only one or the other,  You have to un-join from a Domain to join a workgroup

Comment: Yes, but can it be in a Workgroup and in AD (= Active Directory) at the same time?

Comment: A workgroup machine can join AD groups without being on a domain. Membership settings in AD.  The username of such a machine will show up in AD.

Comment: That's what mine's set up for in such case: afaik joining corporate AD is the very thing that's done upon completion of W10 installation on a new laptop. Wrt the # of members in my workgroup and those m'ship settings in AD now: I'm unsure it's something I have access to: I'd expect it all to be managed solely by our IT.

Comment: You might need to ask your IT department about how they set you up.  It may be their settings requiring you to use domain\user.

Comment: I think I have answered your questions and amended my answer to cover the answers.

Comment: Yeah I'll do that then. Thanks for all the help meanwhile ) I've just marked it as an answer at my side.

Comment: Many thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me: I downloaded the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from Microsoft Store:
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRFJ3PS
This does not prefix domain names to users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mr Bot, I think you are going by the length of my writeup and the presence of a link. I really have no more information to add: The default RDP application appends the offending domain name; but if you download a newer app, it does not have this problem.

Comment: @Raja thank you: I've just tried it briefly and it behaves as you said. I'll just need to spend some time familiarizing with this new app to see if I can "move" to it for good from the old one.