# prevent RDP from randomly appending a domain to username instead of using username in .rdp file

Tags: remote-desktop

I regularly RDP from a *heavily* locked down windows vm to the linux machine I do all my real work in.  I have saved a .rdp file with everything I want to use for the connection, including the username.  This usually works fine.  However roughly once a week, maybe a little less often, it will fail to connect as I expected, the reason being that it appears to have randomly added a domain name in front of my actual username in the username field.  If I remove the domain name and try again it works, and will continue working for another week or so.

I'd like to not have random connection failures though. I'd like to prevent domain name ever being randomly appended to the username.  Why does it occasionally ignore the username in my .rdp file?

I've found some suggestions for modifying registry, though it seems like that shouldn't be necessary when I just want it to respect my .rdp file.  Regardless given how locked own the windows vm is I can not modify registries.  I can barely save a file!  registry hacking isn't really an option for me.

*Yes I know other's have had issues with RDP appending domain in other questions, I have not found any that specifically addressed it ignoring a .rdp file though, or had a useful answer that didn't involve registry hacking.*

Comment: How exactly is the user-name written in the `.rdp` file ? Have you tried the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from Microsoft Store? See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1334115/remote-desktop-connection-without-domain-name).

Comment: @harrymc username:s:<username>  I don't have access to the app store or ability to install well anything sadly.  I can't do much of anything on the windows VM

Comment: Did you see in mylink the alternate syntax for `\username` or `.\username` or others?

Comment: @harrymc I've tried both options.  it didn't help, in fact it seems to make it more likely that domain name is added.

Comment: Long shot : Try `targetname\.\username`.